# Asp Net MVC passar string de conexão para camada de acesso

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou com um projeto que está dividido em camadas, BLL DAL e UI, na UI fica meu projeto MVC, porem surgiu a necessidade que na tela de login o usuário escolha a string de conexão, como posso fazer para passar essa string do projeto MVC para o DAL e continuar usando toda vez que instanciar o DbContext ?

Comment: Conhece o design pattern singleton? se sim sabe como deixar suas classes singleton thread safes(garante a singularidade em diferentes threads)? se você conhecer tudo basta implementar se não conhecer comenta aqui que crio um exemplo pra você!

Comment: Obrigado @FelipeAssunção pelo comentário, se puder postar um exemplo eu agradeço, obrigado.

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue uma solução utilizando o `Singleton` `Design Pattern`

```
using System;

// Exemplo singleton        
public sealed class ConnectionStringManager
{
    #region Singleton design pattern properties
    private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionStringManager> lazy =
        new Lazy<ConnectionStringManager>(() => new ConnectionStringManager());
    public static ConnectionStringManager Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }
    private ConnectionStringManager(){ }
    #endregion

    public string CurrentConnectionString { get; set; }

}

// Exemplo de console application
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Setando a connection string
        ConnectionStringManager.Instance.CurrentConnectionString = "connectionstring selecionado pelo cliente";
        // Voce vai poder acessar a propriedade novamente utilizando 
        // "ConnectionStringManager.Instance.CurrentConnectionString"
        // em qualquer outra classe do sistema.
        Console.WriteLine(ConnectionStringManager.Instance.CurrentConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Se você entender um pouquinho de inglês recomendo a leitura do artigo: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra alternativa para fazer isso também é usando um `hack` para alterar o parâmetro somente leitura `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`, essa solução encontrei no site [http://david.gardiner.net.au/](http://david.gardiner.net.au/2008/09/programmatically-setting.html), ficando assim:

```
var settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nomeDaMinhaConexao"];
var fi = typeof(ConfigurationElement).GetField("_bReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
fi.SetValue(settings, false);
settings.ConnectionString = "minhaStringDeConexao";
```

Coloquei a string de conexão e estava dando o erro `Keyword not supported: “data source”`, para corrigi-lo é só alterar onde tem `&quot;` na string de conexão para aspas simples.

Lembrando que é um `hack`, porem fiz vários testes aqui e a aplicação está funcionando normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar as ConnectionStrings no seu web.config.

Listar apenas os nomes da conexões na tela de login.

Aí vc pode persistir o nome selecionado em uma `Session`, e nas demais camadas vc referencia à biblioteca `System.Web` e recupera o nome selecionado.

E tbm nas suas demais camadas, vc referencia à biblioteca `System.Configuration` e recupera a connection string com `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["nome"]`.

Mas tudo isso é uma péssima prática.

Se vc quer apontar para ambientes distintos, faça com [Web.Config Transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx).

Comment: Referenciar a system.web na infraestrutura de dados e utilizar a sessão para armazenar tal informação é uma péssima pratica realmente, você poderia propor outros meios para resolver o problema dele.

Comment: Sua ideia de usar singletons é uma saída. Outra seria injetar o nome da connstr selecionada nos construtores da camada de acesso à dados.

Comment: Sim, consegue propor essa solução para o nosso amigo?